# Javascript can't get element's value, value equals undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like some help please.

I've recently started learning javascript, and I came across an error I can't fix, it seems simple, yet I can't find a way to fix it.
So, I have a table:

[image: Table]

And the point of the table is to give the squares with the value "X" when clicked, a red background (changing css class), and all others green, but to do that, I need to get the value of the square, and it is always returning "undefined".
[image: HTML OF TABLE]

The HTML table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="normal" id="11" value="0" onclick="alterar('11');">0</td>
        <td class="normal" id="12" value="1" onclick="alterar('12');">1</td>
        <td class="normal" id="13" value="2" onclick="alterar('13');">2</td>
        <td class="normal" id="14" value="X" onclick="alterar('14');">X</td>
        <td class="normal" id="15" value="1" onclick="alterar('15');">1</td>
        <td class="normal" id="16" value="0" onclick="alterar('16');">0</td>
        <td class="normal" id="17" value="0" onclick="alterar('17');">0</td>
    </tr>
        <td class="normal" id="21" value="0" onclick="alterar('21');">0</td>
        <td class="normal" id="22" value="1" onclick="alterar('22');">1</td>
        <td class="normal" id="23" value="2" onclick="alterar('23');">2</td>
        <td class="normal" id="24" value="X" onclick="alterar('24');">X</td>
        <td class="normal" id="25" value="1" onclick="alterar('25');">1</td>
        <td class="normal" id="26" value="0" onclick="alterar('26');">0</td>
        <td class="normal" id="27" value="0" onclick="alterar('27');">0</td>
    </tr>
        <td class="normal" id="31" value="0" onclick="alterar('31');">0</td>
        <td class="normal" id="32" value="1" onclick="alterar('32');">1</td>
        <td class="normal" id="33" value="2" onclick="alterar('33');">2</td>
        <td class="normal" id="34" value="X" onclick="alterar('34');">X</td>
        <td class="normal" id="35" value="1" onclick="alterar('35');">1</td>
        <td class="normal" id="36" value="0" onclick="alterar('36');">0</td>
        <td class="normal" id="37" value="0" onclick="alterar('37');">0</td>
    </tr>
        <td class="normal" id="41" value="0" onclick="alterar('41');">0</td>
        <td class="normal" id="42" value="1" onclick="alterar('42');">1</td>
        <td class="normal" id="43" value="2" onclick="alterar('43');">2</td>
        <td class="normal" id="44" value="X" onclick="alterar('44');">X</td>
        <td class="normal" id="45" value="1" onclick="alterar('45');">1</td>
        <td class="normal" id="46" value="0" onclick="alterar('46');">0</td>
        <td class="normal" id="47" value="0" onclick="alterar('47');">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My javascript code looks like this:

```
function alterar(obj){

  var id = document.getElementById(obj).id;
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;

  if (value == 'X'){
    obj.className='red';
  } else {
    obj.className='green';
    }
}

</script>
```

And if for example, I'd use the square "44", which value is "X", it tells me that [image: value is undefined]

```
    <td class="normal" id="44" value="X" onclick="alterar('44');">X</td>
```

I'd like to thank everyone in advance for their times.

Comment: can't you pass the value in onclick function itselft?

Comment: Post your html table as well as code

Answer (score 2):

The element referred to by `document.getElementById(id)` is a cell of table, i.e. a `<td>` element.

Since it doesn't have a `value` attribute you can't get it. Which explains why you are getting undefined when you try to access it.

To access the text in the cell, you should access `innerText` instead of value.
Like:

```
var value = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function alterar(id){

//var id = document.getElementById(obj).id;
var value = document.getElementById(id).innerText;

if(value == 'X'){
    ......
} else {
    ........
    }
}

</script>
```

this will work because you are already sending id then why you need to get id again

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that td element cannot have value.

But you can leave value attribute and get it by function: `getAttribute`

```
var value = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("value");
```

Also I don't see a point of line:

```
var id = document.getElementById(obj).id;
```

since variable `obj` is your id.

By the way if you try to get few attributes from one element it's a good practice to get element once and save it to variable, eg.

```
function alterar(obj){

    var element = document.getElementById(obj);
    var id = obj;
    var value = element.getAttribute("value");

    if (value == 'X') {
        element.className='red';
    } else {
        element.className='green';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in on click function, which returns clicked element.

```
<td class="normal" id="11" value="0" onclick="alterar(this);">0</td>
```

then inside the function access the element you have passed.

```
function alterar(obj){
    var value = obj.innerText;
    if(value == 'X'){
        obj.className='red';
    } else {
        obj.className='green';
    }
}
```

you don't have to query the element using id.

Answer (score -1):

For my understanding you try to read the value of the `<td>` tag attribute.
If you want to get the `<html>` tag attribute using `java script` use it as below mentioned:

```
// Get all images in the document
var images = document.body.getElementsByTagName("img");
// Get the src attribute of the first one
var src0 = images[0].getAttribute("src");
// Get the src attribute of the second simply by reading the property
var src1 = images[1].src;
```

For Your case get the Value:

```
var id = document.getElementById(obj).id;
var value = id.getAttribute("value");
```

and also you can add class by checking condition like:

```
id.className += " otherclass";
```

I hope this will helpfull for you.